# setBackActionBarWithTitle not working

Tags: android

I have one ActionBar Title with Back button functionality. Some how the button not giving any action. Any help ?

Here is my code

```
@Override
public void setupActionBar() {
    super.setupActionBar();
    setBackActionBarWithTitle(getString(R.string.confirmation));
}


/* method */

public void setBackActionBarWithTitle(String message) {
    Activity activity = (Activity)getActivity();
    /*Fix for 4.4+ compatibility*/
    if (activity instead of BaseDrawerActivity) {
        ((BaseDrawerActivity)activity).getActionBarDrawerToggle()
            .setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
    }
    activity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    activity.getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    activity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    activity.setToolbarTitle(ActionBarUtil
            .createTitle(getActivity(), message));
}
```

Comment: did you try getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.confirmation)); ?

Comment: Actually I do not have that method. It was taken from customized setBackActionBarWithTitle()

Comment: Please post your Activity class